# How many coordinate pairs POLYGON(()) needs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, polygon-creation, well-known-text

I have a .csv file containing a POLYGON(())). For years I have been using 5 pairs of coordinates to draw a 4 sided polygon; the first and last being the same to 'close' the shape. That idea is based on this information - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry

Yesterday I made an error and forgot to 'close' the box, but QGIS still drew a perfectly good Polygon.  Is there a reason I need the closing coordinate pair?
Both these lines create the same result.

```
Name    WKT
5COORD  POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))
4COORD  POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20))
```

Comment: "The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from." The standard requires a closing vertex. If you get lazy and find a client that doesn't support this extension, you might forget that the standard calls for five and come to grief from it.

Comment: It would be more safe to include the closing vertex. If you want to convert CSV data into other formats with ogr2ogr then GDAL may, depending on the driver, either write the invalid polygons as they are in the WKT, or make the polygons valid and show these warnings `Non closed ring detected. To avoid accepting it, set the OGR_GEOMETRY_ACCEPT_UNCLOSED_RING configuration option to NO`.